# Python: queue method wait_for predicate with arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to utilize the `wait_for` method of the queue module. I have a callable for the predicate, and it works if I don't pass any arguments, however the callable requires an `int` argument.

WORKS:

```
self.cv.wait_for(fn, timeout=5.0)
```

FAILS:

```
self.cv.wait_for(fn(1), timeout5.0)
```

This generates the error "bool is not callable".

I've tried the following:

```
self.cv.wait_for((fn(1)) , timeout=5.0)
```

Result: bool is not callable

```
self.cv.wait_for((fn, 1), timeout=5.0)
```

Result: tuple object is not callable

```
self.cv.wait_for((fn, 1)(), timeout=5.0)
```

Result: tuple object is not callable

```
self.cv.wait_for((fn(), 1), timeout=5.0)
```

Result:  fn missing 1 required positional argument: 'int'

fn is a simple function just for testing.

`fn`:

```
def fn(int):
  if int:
   return True
  else:
   return False
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Condition.wait_for`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Condition.wait_for) accepts a predicate that is a callable that accepts no arguments. The return value of the predicate can be anything since all objects have a boolean interpretation.

`self.test` is a callable that accepts one argument, so it is not a suitable predicate. `self.test(1)` is the object that is the *result* of calling the method, which is a `bool`, not a callable.

Your approach with the `lambda` is the simplest and easiest in this case:

```
self.cv.wait_for(lambda: self.test(1), timeout=5.0)
```

If your function is complex enough, you can have it return the predicate callable with appropriate refactoring, instead of wrapping it in a lambda. For example:

```
def fn(i):
    def predicate():
        return bool(i)
    return predicate

...

self.cv.wait_for(fn(1), timeout=5.0)
```

Comment: Thank you, it's greatly appreciated. This raises another question, which I've asked here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53356567/python-queue-threading-waiting-for-queue-to-be-of-specific-size) if you're willing.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it by using a lambda:

```
self.cv.wait_for( lambda: self.test(1), timeout=5.0)
```

But I'm curious as to if there are other ways?