# queue/threading: waiting for queue to be of specific size

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working with a multi-threaded script, where a Controller thread puts a varying number of items in a class queue shared by multiple other Worker threads. I'm looking for a way to have the Controller class wait until all tasks are completed by the other threads. I have something similar to the below:

Worker class

```
class Worker(threading.Thread):
  q = queue.Queue()
  evt_stop = threading.Event()

  def task(self, *data):
    result = data[1] + data[1]
    data[0].q.put(result)

  def __init__(self):
    ...
  def run(self):
    while not Worker.evt_stop.is_set():
      if not Worker.q.empty():
        data = Worker.q.get()
        task(data[0], data[1])
        Worker.q.task_done()
```

Controller class

```
class Controller(threading.Thread):

  evt_stop = threading.Event()

  def qsize(self, n):
    if self.q.qsize() != n:
       return False
    else:
       return True

  def __init__(self):
    self.q = queue.Queue()
    self.await = threading.Condition()

  def run(self):

    r = [<list of unknown length>]

    for i in r:
       Worker.q.put(self, i)

    with self.await:
      if self.await.wait_for(lambda: self.qsize(len(r)), timeout=5.0):
         while not self.q.empty():
            x = self.q.get()
            print(x)
            self.q.task_done()
```

But from my understanding of the answer and clarification provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53355297/python-queue-method-wait-for-predicate-with-arguments), the lambda will always return True, as it is the function object that is returned, not necessarily the value ("self.test(1) is the object that is the result of calling the method, which is a bool, not a callable"). Am I understanding this correctly? Additionally, am I greatly over-complicating this, and a simpler solution exists?

Clarification of intent:

This is essentially a script that performs multiple, network oriented functions. The main thread runs a menu system from which the user can select different network I/O tasks. Each of these tasks runs in a separate thread, instantiated by instances of the controller class. When the script first runs, it instantiates a set of worker threads, typically 4 or 6. The idea is that the user can select one of the instantiated controller class objects, and it will set about fulfilling its logic, which involves sending/receiving data through the worker threads, then modifying that data, and repeating the process. The issue I'm trying to tackle is having the controller object wait until the worker threads complete all the tasks that specific controller instance put into the shared worker class queue. It is unknown in advance how many tasks that will be, as it is dependent upon the results of the very first network I/O task.

Comment: Why do you have method definitions outside classes?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your classes that appear to be functions. Can you include the [full, working code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using the `class` keyword and remove `...`s? From what you're trying to accomplish, it seems like you're overcomplicating things. Seems like filling the work queue, starting `n` threads which work until the queue is empty and having them `join()` the main thread should be sufficient, assuming you can lock the queue.

Comment: @MadPhysicist : Code has been updated, I rushed the copy/paste, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ggorlen : I considered using join, but I won't know how many threads would need to join in advance. I'm also not sure how I would code that, considering there isn't a way (that I know of) for the controller class to be aware of which worker instance picked up the task.

Comment: Can you enumerate all of your requirements for the code? I'm not really clear on what you're trying to accomplish. I'm still seeing `...` and `def Controller(threading.Thread):` which doesn't help me run your code to reproduce the problem. I don't see any reason the worker threads can't identify themselves to the boss, but again, what are your requirements for this (e.g. when does the boss need to know this information).